# Повторная обработка POST запроса(Facebook Messenger)

Tags: php, post, запрос, facebook, messenger

Всем привет!

Вопрос, наверное больше до тех, кто работал с платформой Facebook Messenger. Хотя может это проблема чисто PHP, в общем, перейдем к сути.

Расскажу вкратце как устроен сервис, у нас есть:

- страница фб
- приложение фб
- сервер на котором настроен хук

Иерархия в такой же последовательности как описано, пишем на страницу, оно передает в приложение, сервер хуком ловит сообщения, обрабатывает и отправляет назад.

Суть проблемы (лучше опишу сразу примером и пошагово).
1. Написал сообщение "привет";
2. Получил ответ;
3. Написал следующее сообщение;
4. Получил ответ;
5. Обработало сообщение №1 (хотя не должно было);
6. Отправило ответ

и пункты 5-6 могут несколько раз повториться, такое происходит не часто, но происходит и выглядит так, будто бот спамит сообщениями пользователю.

Посты ловлю вот так:

`$this->response = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"), true, 512, JSON_BIGINT_AS_STRING);`

Может в этом причина? Может есть другой способ ловить их, чтобы оно повторно их не обрабатывало?

Заранее спасибо!